# Flutter - WhatsApp Status Saver App Not Working in android 10 or above

Tags: android, flutter, permissions

I want to create a Whatsapp status saver app in flutter & i did it's succesfully , it's work fine in my android 7 device but not work in my friend android 10 & 11 , whats the reason & how can i solve this??
i also add this permission in android manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and i already allow the permission from user in the starting of app and even user allow this but not working in android 10 or above

my status show screen code

```
final Directory _videoDir =
    Directory('/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses');
    if (!Directory('${_videoDir.path}').existsSync()) {
      return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          const Text(
            'Install WhatsApp\n',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
          ),
          const Text(
            "Your Friend's Status Will Be Available Here",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
          ),
        ],
      );
    } else {
      return VideoGrid(directory: _videoDir);
    }
```

***VideoGrid is my list of images***

Answer (score 0):

the location of the whatsapp status have been changed in recent android version, change your directory to

```
'/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses/'
```

and things should work fine